# SimpleDateFormat not working

Tags: java, date, time, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm tearing my hair off my head on this one. Trying to parse this string into a Date object:

```
Fri, 28 Oct 2011 07:43:18 GMT
```

But it will not work. Instead I get an ParseException:

```
10-28 15:50:12.730: WARN/System.err(31232): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 07:43:18 GMT
```

The code I use is the following (and I have tried multiple tweaks to the formatting string to no avail):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:m:s zzz");
```

I know Javas Date and Time classes leaves a lot to wish for but this one is killing me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Locale.US. Try this instead

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:m:s zzz", Locale.US);
Date date = dateformat.parse("Oct 28 09:53:19 2011");
```

Comment: Well, this alone did not do the trick. However also explicitly setting the timezone with setTimeZone() did work. So it was a combination. I'm giving this one to you anyway, feeling generous.

Answer (score 6):

your format looks more like this (double mm and double ss):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz");
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out a subtle error, and posting your first answer (It also helps that it is right;-)

Comment: That is not an error, one or two (even three) 'm' or 's' does bit matter. From documentation: "Text: if the count is 4 or more, use the full form; otherwise use a short or abbreviated form if one exists."